# Calculating in closed form $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}(1,-x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Can you confirm the following result? Mathematica and other computational stuff I used seem
unable to do anything about this result. Maybe to confirm it numerically?
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}(1,-x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$ 
$$=\frac{3}{8} \pi  \log ^2(2)-\frac{1}{4} \gamma  \pi  \log (2)-\frac{1}{16} \text{StieltjesGamma}^{(0,1)}\left(1,\frac{1}{4}\right)+\frac{1}{16} \text{StieltjesGamma}^{(0,1)}\left(1,\frac{3}{4}\right)+2\log (2) G $$

Let's go a bit further and see a more advanced version

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\text{PolyLog}^{(2,0)}(1,-x)}{1+x^2} \, dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{48} \left(3 \zeta ^{(2,0)}\left(2,\frac{3}{4}\right)-3 \zeta ^{(2,0)}\left(2,\frac{1}{4}\right)+6 (\gamma -1+\log (4)) \zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(2,\frac{1}{4}\right)-6 (\gamma -1+\log (4)) \zeta ^{(1,0)}\left(2,\frac{3}{4}\right)-6 \gamma  \text{StieltjesGamma}^{(0,1)}\left(1,\frac{1}{4}\right)+6 \gamma  \text{StieltjesGamma}^{(0,1)}\left(1,\frac{3}{4}\right)+96 G \left(\gamma -2 \log ^2(2)+\log (4)\right)+24 \pi  \gamma _1 \log (2)-28 \pi  \log ^3(2)+36 \gamma  \pi  \log ^2(2)\right)$$

Both integrals come from my research and it's for the first time I calculated in closed forms integrals with partial derivatives of the polylog. I'm also curious if you have other example of such integrals with $\operatorname{Li}_s^{(n,0)}(x), \ n\ge 1$ that are evaluated in closed forms?

If it's of any importance, I can find the closed forms for the whole family

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\text{PolyLog}^{(n,0)}(1,-x)}{1+x^2} \, dx \ , n\ge1.$$

Comment: I am familiar with quite a few special functions (all those in A&S and PBM), but not with 2-parameter PolyLog (nor 2-parameter SiteltjesGamma).  Could you give some references?

Comment: @JacquesCarette Well, I could have used the notation $\operatorname{Li}_s^{(n,0)}(x)$ (where $n$ is the $n$th derivative with respect to $s$), and for the second part, it's about  generalized Stieltjes constants (where for this case we consider the proper partial derivative), see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_constants.

Comment: $$\gamma^{(0,1)} \!\left(1, \tfrac{3}{4} \right) - \gamma^{(0,1)} \!\left(1, \tfrac{1}{4} \right) = \zeta^{(1,0)} \!\left(2, \tfrac{3}{4} \right)- \zeta^{(1,0)} \!\left(2, \tfrac{1}{4} \right)-16G$$

Comment: I can confirm your results for both integrals. They can be evaluated in _Mathematica_ using an [integral representation](http://functions.wolfram.com/10.08.07.0001.01) $\operatorname{Li}_\nu(z)=\frac{z}{\Gamma(\nu)}{\large\int}_0^\infty \frac{t^{\nu-1}}{e^t-z}\!\;dt$ and changing the order of integration.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov Thanks! Indeed, it's a way that works.